# 無償評価版IBMアカウントの法人契約移行について

Tags: bluemix, watson-api

現在Bluemix上のWatson APIを利用しており、そちらに関する質問です。

前提として、先月まで無償評価版であったアカウントを、今月途中から法人契約(パスポート・アドバンテージ契約)に変更しました。
それに伴い、無償評価版であった際に作成したWatson APIのインスタンス(NLC, R&R)に対しても課金が始まりました。
今後それらを利用する予定がないため削除したいのですが、Console画面上に現れず削除することができません。(地域、スペースが正しいことも確認済。)
なお、使用状況ダッシュボード上には表示され、日々課金額が増えている状況です。
また、REST APIでのアクセスを試みても認証が通らず削除することができません。

このような場合どのように対処すればよいのでしょうか。
そもそも、同様の状況になった方はいますでしょうか。

ご支援よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

まずは法人契約されたときの窓口に連絡されてはいかがでしょうか？
こちらの連絡先でもよいかもしれません。
http://www-935.ibm.com/services/jp/ja/it-services/software-supportguide-center-contact.html

こちらも参考までに。
http://qiita.com/KenichiSekine/items/212bee6f2a8cdfaae497

Comment: ありがとうございます。
経緯としては、法人契約時の窓口の営業の方にこちらを案内していただきました。
教えていただいたリンク先にも投げてみたいと思います。